# QVideoProbe control destroyed while it's still being referenced

Tags: c++, windows, qt5, qt-creator

I created a QCamera, and a QVideoProbe, which will allow me to access each frame of the video.
The problem is that every time I close the app, I get this message in Qt Creator: 'QVideoProbe control destroyed while it's still being referenced!!!'.

I'm using Qt 5.11 on Windows 8.1. My compilator is MSVC 2015 (32-bit).

Here's my code:

```
Window::Window()
{
    if(!checkCameraAvailability())
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", "No camera is available");
        return;
    }

    m_camera = new QCamera;
    m_camera->setCaptureMode(QCamera::CaptureVideo);

    m_videoProbe = new QVideoProbe(this);

    if(!m_videoProbe->setSource(m_camera))
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", "setSource");
        return;
    }

    connect(m_videoProbe, SIGNAL(videoFrameProbed(QVideoFrame)), this, SLOT(cameraFrameProbed(QVideoFrame)));
    // For now the slot 'cameraFrameProbed' is empty

    m_camera->start();
}
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I replaced this line:

```
m_videoProbe = new QVideoProbe(this);
```

with this one:

```
m_videoProbe = new QVideoProbe;
```

But I still don't understand what was wrong with the first line.

**EDIT: The previous solution has a memory leak! Here's the correct one:**

I forgot to mention the parent of the QCamera when constructing it, there were actually 2 memory leaks...

So the code becomes:

```
m_camera = new QCamera(this);
m_videoProbe = new QVideoProbe(this);
```

And now it works!

Thank you so much Jeremy Friesner!

Comment: Before, your QVideoProbe was being made a child-object of your Window object (`this`), whereas after the change, the QVideoProbe has no parent.  That means that unless you manually `delete m_videoProbe` on shutdown, your QVideoProbe object is being leaked.  You've just traded one problem for another; now instead of a warning message you have a memory leak.  Your best bet is to grep through the Qt source code to see where the warning message is coming from, and based on that code that causes it, figure out what exactly is referencing your object, and add code to your app to un-reference it.

Comment: It might be as easy as calling m_camera->stop() from your Window destructor (I haven't used QVideoProbe so I can't say for sure)

Comment: Thank you for your replies! I just fixed the memory leak, I completely forgot about the delete. The warning comes from here: [link](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/directshow/common/directshowvideoprobecontrol.cpp.html). But I don't understand how to dereference the object.

Comment: I also tried calling m_camera->stop() but that doesn't fix the problem. The warning appears when the QVideoProbe is deleted.

Comment: I just edited my post, you were right about the memory leak.